# Why didn't Yoda & Obi-Wan stay around to help rebuild the Jedi Order?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, jedi-training

In both canon and Legends, Obi-Wan and Yoda can choose when to release their retention of consciousness after death. In both canonicities, though, why do they not stay around to help Luke rebuild the Jedi Order?

They are the last retainers of millennia of Jedi knowledge and wisdom that will be lost upon their departure - it will take decades or even centuries to recover them all from the archives at the Temple. Did they really think it wise to let a farm boy who barely qualifies as a Jedi Knight to play the role traditionally reserved for Jedi Masters without the slightest guidance?

Considering the ease of falling to the dark side without proper guidance and training, one would think that, if your goal is to prevent the triumph of the dark side, you would also aim to prevent its resurgence. Training Luke until he is ready to become a Jedi Master - and probably raising the first new generation to Knighthood - is probably the least Obi-Wan and Yoda can do to start the New Jedi Order off on a good footing.

So, why didn't they? I'm looking for both canon and Legends answers, as even though the story of Luke's founding of a New Jedi Order is different, the same question can be asked nonetheless since the rationale for why Obi-Wan and Yoda should have stayed is the same.

Comment: They were like "Meh too much work, we'll just wait for a few years". #Canon

Comment: Keep in mind Vader is still actively hunting Jedi. They were both on their respective planets as they helped mask their force presence. If they started moving around or started training other Jedi, it would be very easy for Vader to find them and destroy them and their work.

Comment: "Let's have the guys who ran the version that failed build the new one!"

Comment: @Hatandboots I'm referring to rebuilding the Jedi Order AFTER Endor, when Vader is dead. Dead people don't kill (not in this universe).

Comment: @thegreatjedi so you mean why don't they come back as force ghosts to pass on whatnot?

Comment: @Hatandboots yeah. We already see in Legends that Luke did a lot of "reinventing the wheel". With apparently no access to the Jedi Temple in Disney canon, I suspect it won't be too different. Could have saved a lot of effort and risk if Yoda and Obi-Wan are around to give a headstart. What's the odds Kylo would still turn to the dark side?

Comment: Do we actually know that they didn't? Given that all previous continuity is thrown into the _Legends_ level of canon, and our information from the _new_ canon about the founding and fall of the new Jedi Order is sparse at best, do we actually know that they _didn't_ stick around to advise Luke?

Answer (score 4):

One of the differences between Jedi in episodes 5-7 as opposed to 1-3 is that Jedi (at least the more powerful ones) seem to be able to hone their abilities a lot faster in the later movies (5-7). In 1-3 they need years of training but in the later movies Yoda and Obi-Wan seem to be willing to give Luke the rank of Jedi pretty quickly and on top of that his abilities were good enough to defeat Vader with less training than we'd expect from 1-3. In Episode 7 Rey is able to use her abilities fairly well very quickly, whether being able to do mind-tricks or using the force to get the lightsaber before battling Kylo Ren.

They saw Luke as being very powerful and as someone who overcame the Dark Side in a huge way when he was tested.

Comment: He failed at the cave non the less though

Comment: @Thomas that was before he defeated Vader. He didn't show up a Jedi, he became one.

Comment: @cbender Unfortunately your assertion isn't supported statistically. Given Luke & Kylo's Skywalker lineage, and Rey's questionable lineage, we may have to consider them as naturally strong in the Force. Three powerful Jedi aren't enough to prove everyone can learn a lot faster now. If it's so, Kylo wouldn't be able to exterminate an entire order so easily.

Comment: @thegreatjedi you very well might be right. But that doesn't change the fact that Luke was likely considered highly qualified in Yoda's and Obi-Wan's mind which was the question. The speed part might be a false conclusion. But I'd definitely say it's possible.

Comment: @cbender I'll have to see more literature of post-Endor Luke to make my judgement on him. As it stands, the Luke I know immediately after Endor may be strong enough to resist the dark side, but isn't ready to become the Yoda of a new order and certainly does not possess even a significant sliver of the knowledge and wisdom Yoda himself can possibly share. I personally won't be willing to entrust the Return of the Jedi Order to him alone yet lol

Comment: @thegreatjedi and